# Use "must_not exists" using elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

For one of my project, I need to determine all record from my ES index where a field is missing.
See an example of my data stored in my ES index below :

```
{
  "schema": "https://sample.org/schemas/user_v0.0.1.json",
  "barcode": "210000001",
  "birth_date": "1961-11-24", 
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "end_date": "2021-03-30",
      "start_date": "2020-03-30"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "schema": "https://sample.org/schemas/user_v0.0.1.json",
  "barcode": "210000002",
  "birth_date": "1980-03-17", 
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "subscriptions": []
}, {
  "schema": "https://sample.org/schemas/user_v0.0.1.json",
  "barcode": "210000003",
  "birth_date": "1980-03-17", 
  "first_name": "Patty",
  "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

I would like to determine which of my users doesn't have any subscriptions. In my exemple, 'Bob Smith' and 'Patty Smith' should be returned. I need to do that using Python ElasticSearch DSL query.

At this time, I can filter my search to retrieve only users, but despite many tries I didn't find the way to get only users "must_not" + "exists" subscriptions.

```py
results = Search()\
          .filter('term', schema='https://sample.org/schemas/user_v0.0.1.json')
          # complete filter with : "Must not exists subscription"
          .source('barcode')
          .scan()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Python DSL, but REST query for finding those  users who doesn't have any subscriptions is :

```
    {
     "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "subscriptions",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "subscriptions"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great. But notice that this is for nested field types only.

Answer (score 4):

I continue to search and to test and it seems I found the solution for my problem

```py
    query = Search()\
        .filter('term', schema='https://sample.org/schemas/user_v0.0.1.json')\
        .filter('bool', must_not=[Q('exists', field="subscriptions")])\
        .source('barcode')\
        .scan()
```

I hope it could help someone !

Comment: A more succinct way to write the must_not exists is to use the `.exclude()` method, like so: `.exclude("exists", field="subscriptions")`

Comment: What Q? Ah.... from elasticsearch_dsl import Q